# What is the reason in each of these subgroups of order $2^n$, each element's lower $n$ bits are distinct & form all possible $4$-bit patterns?

Tags: group-theory, modular-arithmetic, cyclic-groups, bit-strings

Let's take the example of the additive group $\Bbb Z/176\Bbb Z$

This has a subgroup of order $2^3$: $[0, 22, 44, 66, 88, 110, 132, 154]$

If you check the lower $3$ bits of each element in this subgroup, you will find $2^3$ distinct bit patterns covering each bit pattern from $0$ to $2^3$

Likewise this is the subgroup of order $2^4 = [0, 11, 22, 33, ...., 165]$

If you check the lower $4$ bits of each element in this subgroup, you will find $2^4$ distinct bit patterns covering each bit pattern from $0$ to $2^4$

Why is this so? Is there is name for this? Or is there a proof for how this is always true? And are these some conditions under which this is true?

Answer (score 2):

It's because your examples consist of some (in the first case) or all (in the second case) multiples of $11$, and $11$ is relatively prime to $16$.  So in the second case, you get all possible remainders modulo $16$.  In the first case the last bit is always $0$ but the previous 3 bits give all possibilities modulo $8$.

Something like this will work in any similar case.  For example if you have the first $9$ multiples of $11$ and you write them in base $3$, you will find that the last two digits give all possible combinations.

Comment: The first subgroup is of order 8, so why does it matter if 11 is relatively prime to 16?

Comment: Then it's automatically prime to $8$ too of course.

Comment: Is there a reason why these subgroups of order 8 & order 16 are composed of elements which are multiples of 11 which is coprime to 8 & 16. Does it have something to do with the fact that the order of the main group is $11*16 = 176$. I am trying to find a general rule where this will be true

Comment: Something like if you have a group of order $p*2^{n}$, where $p$ is prime, then elements of subgroups of order $2^{n}, 2^{n-1}$ etc will be coprime to p. Is there some generalization like this which I should try to derive?

Comment: Also, here the main group is modulo (a*b) & of order (a*b) with a = 11 & b = 16, and the subgroup of order 16 has 11 as a generator & the subgroup of order 16/2 has 2*11 as a generator. Is there some generalisation for this?

Comment: In this question you are asking about groups $\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$, which are very special.  It is easy to list all subgroups of this group: $\{ka\mid 0\le k<m/a\}$ for each factor $a$ of $m$.  If you think about it a bit, this will explain all your observations.  Of course there are groups not of this form, and then things can get more complex.